# Fatal error: Call to undefined method options::getCategoriesbug() in /var/www/bugreporting.php on line 67

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Getting this complete error (same as title) from my apache logs:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method options::getCategoriesbug() in /var/www/bugreporting.php on line 67

bugreporting.php:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?= lang('category', 'Category'); ?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-prom" name="pkg_category" style="padding-left: 8px;">
                                <?php 
                                $id = $_GET['id'];
                                if($id == '1'){
                                echo options::getCategoriesbug($id);
                            }?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

and functions.php:

```
function getCategoriesbug($p, $db, $name, $res, $id){

global $db;
global $name;
global $res;
global $id;

$res = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM bugcategories");
if ($res) {

    $ret = '';
    foreach ($res as $row) {
        $id2 = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];


    }

    return $ret;
        require('../bugreporting.php');
}
```

}

If anyone knows what the cause of the issue is I would appreciate some help because at this point I've been trying to fix it for over an hour.

Comment: Have you included `functions.php` in your php file?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud Yes. It is at the top with all other includes

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getCategoriesbug` does not seem to be enclosed in a class named `options`.
Then, the correct way to call this simple function is:

```
echo getCategoriesbug($id);
```

If the function `getCategoriesbug` is a method enclosed in a class named `options` (that you are not showing here), then the definition of your method is incorrect. It should be:

```
class options {

   static function getCategoriesbug($p, $db, $name, $res, $id) {
       // some code here
   }

   // maybe more methods here
}
```

Documentation:
- [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)
- [static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)